# Convector controller don't add a model to blockchain

Tags: typescript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, convector

I am creating a university voting app with the convector suite 
when I add a candidate the blockchain returns success but I want to see the data it doesn't appear
so this is the controller 
     @Invokable()
     public async addcondidate (
    @Param(yup.string()) id1 : string,
    @Param(yup.string()) cid : string,

```
@Param(yup.string()) id : string,
@Param(yup.string()) party : string
 ){
const existing = await Test.getOne(id);
const celection = await Election.getOne(id1);



if (!existing || !existing.id) {
  throw new Error('user does not exist ');
}
if(existing.condidate){

  throw new Error('the user is already a condidate');
}else {
  //let nowdate = moment() ;
  //if (nowdate.isAfter(celection.nstardate)&&nowdate.isBefore(celection.nfinisdate)){

  // date comparision !!!
  const condidate = new Condidate();
  condidate.name = existing.name;
  condidate.id = cid;
  condidate.party = party ;
  condidate.election = celection.id ;
  existing.condidate = true;
  existing.save();
  condidate.save();
  //}else { throw new Error('you cant not do so in this time !!');}



}
```

and this the model condidate

```
export class Condidate extends ConvectorModel<Test> {
@ReadOnly()
@Required()
public readonly type = 'vote.condidate';
@Required()
@Required()
public id : string;
@Required()
@Validate(yup.string())
public name: string;
@Required()
@Validate(yup.string())
public party: string;
@Required()
@Validate(yup.string())
public election: string;
@Default(0)
@Required()
@Validate(yup.number())
public votes: number;
```

Comment: Please do not give us your file. It will be inconvenient for your reader. Just copy and paste the snippet of the related codes.

Comment: sorry, I have changed the post